# Merge workbooks in a folder and rename sheets to previous filenames

Tags: excel, vba

slightly struggling with the following.. would be amazing if anyone could help!!

I have a folders each containing different excel files consistently named "Provider A Product X Month Year", and each contain either one sheet only or the standard Sheet 1, .., Sheet 3

Now I would love to merge all of those workbooks (only the first Sheet in case of multiple sheets in a workbook) into one, and have all sheets to be renamed "Month Year", same as in the respective original filnames. I've seen [Merging Several Workbooks Into One Workbook with All the Workbooks as Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648118/merging-several-workbooks-into-one-workbook-with-all-the-workbooks-as-sheets) which partially helps but doesnt fully answer..

Alternatively, or even better, it would be best to have all files merge into the same worksheet, underneath each other, and have the "Month Year" part of the filename be an extra column. I.e. if I have data in e.g. A1:D50 then the macro would add a new column A and write "Month Year" into each of A1:A50

Any thoughts very much appreciated!

Thanks
Markus

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim oShell As Object
    Dim strFolderPath As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strMonthYear As String

    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    On Error Resume Next
    strFolderPath = oShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select Folder", 0).Self.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    Set oShell = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Len(strFolderPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wsDest = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    wsDest.Range("A1").Value = "Month Year"
    strFileName = Dir(strFolderPath & "*.xls*")

    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        With Workbooks.Open(strFolderPath & strFileName)
            .Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .Close False
        End With
        strMonthYear = WorksheetFunction.Trim(Right(Replace(strFileName, " ", String(99, " ")), 198))
        wsDest.Range(wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1), wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(, -1)).Value = strMonthYear
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set wsDest = Nothing

End Sub
```