# Merge Multiple Workbooks from Multiple Files into Summary Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to macros and have searched for hours and hours without any meaningful progress on this project. This has been incredibly frustrating and I have yet to find anything close to a solution without continuing to make a mess out of my files.

I'm trying to take a summary file located in 'C:\Users\prosemur\Financials\Monthly Sales Reports' and populate two sheets within it from workbooks located in two separate files.  This will be a monthly sales report that will utilize daily sales reports generated from a point of sale to form a summary workbook.

The first sheet I need to populate in the summary file is 'Data Entry' from the workbook 'August 2013.xlsx' and each row needs to pull information from data from files located in C:\Users\prosemur\Financials\DSRs\2013\August (using Autust 2013 as the example here).  The information I need from these workbooks are from 'Sheet 1' within each sales report.  What I need is the info from cell C70 of the sales report into cell F12 on the
monthly report.  I then need D70 into G12, E70 into H12, F70 into I12, and C74 into H12.  The other tricky part is that K12 on the monthly report needs to be the sum of G70 and G74.

Once row 12 is populated with the sales report from Day 1 of the month, it needs to go onto the next day in that month until all the files in that folder have been completed.

I would attach the files, but I don't see anyway to do that here.

If anyone can give me any sort of direction on how to complete, or even correctly start it correctly without being doomed from the beginning, that would be very much appreciated.  I really need some direction on this and have no clue how to get really going on it.  Thanks in advance, I really appreciate it!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15651947/641067 for the process to merge multiple files in a folder into one. The tweaking needed to this answer is the selection of specific cells.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this site is for programmers to help other programmers develop.  Even the programmers who answer many questions will sometimes ask their own questions.  We are all learning.

To the extent that I understand your requirement, its solution involves no complicated VBA so I assume you are a complete beginner. If someone wrote a macro for you, you would not understand it and could not amend it if it was not exactly what you wanted. We would not be helping you develop by giving you a solution.

Search the internet for "Excel VBA tutorial". There are many to choose from and most are free. They are all different so try a few and complete one that matches your learning style. Alternatively visit a large library or bookshop where you will find a selection of Excel VBA primers. I suggest the library first so you can try a few before visiting the bookshop to buy the one you prefer.  The time spent learning VBA will quickly repay itself.

Break your problem down into tiny steps.  Write a macro to solve step 1.  Then write a macro to solve steps 1 and 2.  And so on.

It seems to me the first step in your requirement is opening a number of workbooks.

Open the Excel VBA Editor, Click Help and search for "workbook open".  When I do this, the fourth search result is "Opening a workbook".  This contains the code:

```
Sub OpenUp()
    Workbooks.Open("C:\MyFolder\MyBook.xls")
End Sub
```

Wrong folder and wrong file but this shows the statement you need.

Try writing a macro that opens all the workbooks you need.  That macro should end with the workbook holding the macro and all the workbooks you need open.

Close the other workbooks then look up "Workbook close".  This time the relevant search result is "Close method".  Within that you will find "Close method as it applies to the Workbook object."

For version 2 of your macro, close all the workbooks without saving changes.

Continue like this with tiny steps.  If a macro fails post your code and say "It does X but you want it to do Y."  Someone will help.

Good luck.

Comment: Why the -1?  I thought this answer would help the OP.  Do you disagree?