# sum of group by column for each sheets in a workbook in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel workbook which has a number of sheets. And each sheet has a table. Now i would like to sum from each sheet group by any category.

sheet1

```
prodcutid    quantity

100             2
101             3
102             3
104             4
```

sheet2

```
prodcutid    quantity

100             2
101             3
104             4
```

sheet3

```
prodcutid    quantity


101             3
104             4
```

results shoud be as 
result sheet

```
prodcutid    quantity

100             4
101             9
102             3
104             12
```

Comment: The easiest would be to copy all the data into 1 temp sheet and create a Pivot :)

Comment: You can also use formulas to achieve what you want

Comment: i would like to create macro. Would you help me?

Comment: `Would you help me?` : Definitely :) But for that I would like to see some effort from your side. Use `.Find` to search for the values in all the sheets and then simply add the  values. Here is a link which will get you started. http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/ (See SECTION 4) Give it a try and if you get stuck, post the code that you tried and then we will take it from there?

Comment: Kindly use the addin RDBMerge. RDBMerge is a user friendly way to Merge Data from Multiple Excel Workbooks, csv and xml files into a Summary Workbook. Once you have the data you can create the pivot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186302/merge-multiple-workbooks-from-different-folders-into-one/15188080#15188080

Answer (score 1):

Install RDB Merge Addin. Once its installed you will get an option in Data Tab.

[image]

Once you click on RDB Merge icon will get below screen.

[image]

Follow the below steps.
[image]

Output will be like below image

[image]

Insert a row at top and add your headers.

Pivot

[image].

Note : My data are dummy.