# Copy every worksheet from one excel file to another

Tags: vba, excel, file-io, copy-paste

Having this, probably easy to solve problem, but without any programing skills its hard for me to crack...

I made an excel file with a button, a macro assigned to it.

What it should do :

1. Open another xls file, for which the user can search on harddrive
2. copy every sheet from the opened file
3. Paste it to the original file and close the one it was copied from.

So far I got this:

```
Sub Importfile()

Dim sFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook

sFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("*.xls,*.xls")

If sFile <> "False" Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)


    'Copy and paste code , where I dont know what to do




    wb.Close
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Excel 2003? did you try using macro recorder to do so?

Comment: You can use the freely avialable RDBMerge addin for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186302/merge-multiple-workbooks-from-different-folders-into-one/15188080#15188080

Comment: this question is asked almost daily on stackoverflow, one of the most seen duplicates for excel...

Comment: Good ide KazJaw. Thanks! My only problem is now that when I start to record this , than its for a certain file what I open. But I want it to be coded as any file the user has opened.

Comment: Look at how the recorded macro does the copying, implement that in your macro. Are you just trying to duplicate a single workbook or collect worksheets from many workbooks?

Comment: its about several sheets from a workbook. If I use the recorded macro code , than its looking for that file , from which I copied when recording. But I want that file to be activated, which the user will open. Hope I'm clear :)

Comment: Set wb = Workbooks.Activate(sFile) something like this I guess..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example code is right, looking at the recorded macro code should have shown you how to use the `worksheet.copy` method. Using that you would just have to loop through all the worksheets in your newly opened workbook and copy them to your original workbook.

I've used a `For Each`, you could also just a plain `For` or any other sort of loop that you like.

```
Sub Importfile()

Dim sFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

sFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("*.xls,*.xls")

If sFile <> "False" Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        ws.Copy before:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Next ws

    wb.Close
End If

End Sub
```

The macro works fine for me! Please make sure that you have placed the code in the correct location.

In the image below "Book1" is your original sheet (the one you are copying sheets *to*) the macro code should be inserted into a "module" (the red square) and *not* any of the ones in the orange square. If you do not have a "module 1" (or any other) you need to insert a new one by looking in the "insert" menu at the top of the vba editor.

[image]

Comment: Looks nice and simple. I get an error message : method copy of object '_Worksheet' failed.

Comment: ws.Copy before:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) -this is indicated as problem. Even if I change "ThisWorkbook" to my original files name where the macro is running

Comment: Indeed that was the problem.. I very much appreciate your help. Great skill you have mastered :)